# Python-Vim function to use arrow keys to select an item from a list

Tags: python, vim

I'm playing around trying to emulate some [Ctrl-P](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim)-like behaviour in Vim. What I have so far:

1. User calls my function.
2. A window is opened with a list of items in it.
3. A prompt is displayed under the list of items.
4. I want the user to be able to use the up and down arrows to select from the items but without leaving the prompt (in which they can also type).

I have got 1-3 mostly under control but am struggling with #4. I have got as far as this:

```python
python << EOF
import vim

def MyWindow():
  # Create a new window at the bottom
  vim.command("below new")
  vim.current.buffer.append("123")
  vim.current.buffer.append("234")
  vim.current.buffer.append("345")

  vim.command("redraw")

  vim.command("setl cursorline")
  vim.command("echon '>> ' | echoh None")

  while True:
    vim.command("let x = getchar()")
    character_code = vim.eval("x")

    if character_code == "13":
      # Exit by pressing Enter
      break
    elif character_code == "\x80kd": # Down
      vim.command("keepj norm! j")
      vim.command("redraw")
EOF
command! MyWindow python MyWindow()
```

Now the first down arrow keypress works perfectly, but subsequent down arrow kepresses don't, even though the code in the "if down key pressed" case is executed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just realised I can make it work by doing this:

```
elif character_code == "\x80kd": # Down
  vim.command("keepj norm! j")
  vim.command("setl cursorline")  # <-- This fixed it
  vim.command("redraw")
```

But I have no idea why or if this is a sensible thing to do.